# this.props.navigations.state.params is undefined when navigating with TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I can't pass parameters to screens when i am navigating between `TabNavigator` . `this.props.navigations.state.params` return `undefined`. Yet, there is no problem with `StackNavigator` navigation.

Any solution to pass my params from `TabNavigator` ?

Comment: You'll need to add some code. No way to tell what the problem could be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Navigating from one tab to another ?